# MySQL Inner join query showing duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, join, select, left-join, inner-join

I have written following `MySQL` Inner Join query. The Mysql version is `8.0.18-commercial`

```
select r.network->>"$[0].name" , s.server, s.ipAddr,
    from table1 e
    inner join table2 s
        on e.objectId  = s.envId
    inner join resources r
        on e.objectId  = r.envId    
    inner join tpgs g
        on e.accountId  = g.objectId      
    inner join msgTable a
        on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from msgTable a where a.logId = s.AuditId)  
    ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC ;
```

However, I am getting duplicate entries for few of the records.

Here, `s.server` should appear only once.

I have added `group by` as below but getting an error:

```
select r.network->>"$[0].name" , s.server, s.ipAddr,
    from table1 e
    inner join table2 s
        on e.objectId  = s.envId
    inner join resources r
        on e.objectId  = r.envId    
    inner join tpgs g
        on e.accountId  = g.objectId      
    inner join msgTable a
        on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from msgTable a where a.logId = s.AuditId)  
    GROUP BY s.server
    ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC ;
```

Error:

```
Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.s.ipAddr' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Please suggest how to update the query so as to eliminate duplicate rows.

Comment: you  have 1:n relations in your tables, so group by the values that only should appear once anbd decide with aggregation functions what to do with the columns that are not unique. Still for an accuurate answer please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That's how joins work. They produce duplicates for related tables.

Comment: Here, `s.server` should appear only once.

Comment: @meallhour How so? The joins do not say that. It can appear many times.

Comment: How can I modify the query so that I have unique entry for `s.server`?

Comment: I have updated my question and also included `group by` clause

Comment: as i said for the rest of the columns use one of these https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: got it thanks. i have posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get desired result by modifying the query as below:

```
select MAX(r.network->>"$[0].name") , s.server, MAX(s.ipAddr),
    from table1 e
    inner join table2 s
        on e.objectId  = s.envId
    inner join resources r
        on e.objectId  = r.envId    
    inner join tpgs g
        on e.accountId  = g.objectId      
    inner join msgTable a
        on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from msgTable a where a.logId = s.AuditId)  
    GROUP BY s.server 
    ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC ;
```